# How to stop a goroutine if we fail to listen from a channel passed to that routine

Tags: go

I have encountered an issue w.r.t goroutines. Suppose there is a channel and we passed this channel over a goroutine from main. Now if we fail to listen on this channel from main (in case a return/panic occur before listening). The goroutine doesn't stop. How to stop this goroutine in case of error?

In case of multiple call to the function in goroutine the number of routine keeps on increasing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func test(a chan string) {
    defer func() {
        close(a)
        fmt.Println("channel close")
    }()
    fmt.Println("sending to channel")
    a <- "1"
    fmt.Println("sent to channel")
}

func method() string {

    fmt.Println("method starting no. of routine=>",
        runtime.NumGoroutine())
    b := make(chan string)

    go test(b)
    fmt.Println("method current no. of routine=>",
        runtime.NumGoroutine())

    return "error" //if this is executed the routines keeps on
    //increasing
    a := <-b
    return a
}

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("final main no. of routine=>",
        runtime.NumGoroutine())
    i := 0
    //firing 10 request for method
    for {
        if i < 10 {
               fmt.Println(method())
               i++
        } else {
               break
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
method starting no. of routine=> 1

method current no. of routine=> 2

error

method starting no. of routine=> 2

method current no. of routine=> 3

error

method starting no. of routine=> 3

method current no. of routine=> 4

error
```

.....keeps on increasing like this

Comment: If main returns (or crashes) the program terminates, no matter what. But in general that's what the default case in a select statement is for: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6

Comment: For this case you should use the context pattern. https://blog.golang.org/context

Comment: you for loop creates unbounded number of goroutines. I d never do that.for full control, see select and context.

Comment: I want the test routine to be stopped after the error is occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a routine can be stop by context.
Before you use context, you should know only routine with loop are expected stop-control, those deadable routines are no need to stop.

context example:

```golang
func main(){
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go func(c context.Context){
        for {
            select{
                case <-c.Done():
                   fmt.Println("exit success")
                default:
                   // service
                   fmt.Println("my logic service loop")
            }    
        }
    }(ctx)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
   cancel()
}
```